# Calculate total qty of all product id's with groupBy results to only 1 product id

Tags: php, laravel

I have two tables:

`Products -> id, total_qty`

`Inventory -> id, prod_id (FK), type, qty`

Column 'type' here refers to "in" or "out" movement of products.

Inventory table `belongsTo` Products table and Products table `hasMany` relationship to Inventory.

To get each product's total quantity:
`total_qty = in - out`

Example table
Inventory

```
|id |prod_id |type |qty |
|:--|:-------|:----|:---|
|1  |1       |in   |5   |
|2  |1       |out  |2   |
|3  |2       |in   |5   |
|4  |2       |out  |3   |
```

Query result should be

```
|prod_id|total_qty|
|:------|:--------|
|1      |3        |
|2      |2        |
```

Here is my current code:

```
$in = DB::table('inventory')
      ->select('products_id')
      ->groupBy('products_id')
      ->where('type', 'LIKE', '%in%')
      ->sum('qty');
$out = DB::table('inventory')
      ->select('products_id')
      ->groupBy('products_id')
      ->where('type', 'LIKE', '%out%')
      ->sum('qty');
$total_qty = $in - $out;
```

This code here outputs product 1 only. It did get the correct total quantity. However, I need it to get EACH products `total qty`.

Also, how can I save the resulting `total qty` of each product to `Products` table?

Answer (score 0):

To update `total_qty`, the best way is to update it when inserting record in `inventory` table. See bellow code (Please use Your own `Model` names, as I used by assuming them).

```
$inventory=Inventory::create([
           'products_id' => 2,
           'type' =>  'in'
           'qty'  => 7
      ]);
// get product to update total_qty

$updateProduct=Product::find($invetory->products_id);
if ($inventory->type == 'in') {
    $updateProduct->total_qty=$updateProduct->total_qty + $inventory->qty;
} elseif ($inventory->type == 'out') {
    $updateProduct->total_qty=$updateProduct->total_qty - $inventory->qty;
}
$updateProduct->save();
```

`$updateProduct->save();` will update total_qty in products table.